# convert these modules from verilog to VHDL

Tags: vhdl

please can anyone help me convert the following Verilog to vhdl. Thank you.

```
module adder(a,b,out); //adder

input [31:0] a,b; //inputs
output [31:0] out; //outputs
reg [31:0] out;
always @(a or b) begin 
    out = a+b;
end 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LIBRARY ieee; 
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is 
  PORT ( 
    a : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    b : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); 
    regout : out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) 
); 
end adder; 

ARCHITECTURE adder_arch of adder is 
begin 

regout <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + unsigned(b));

end adder_arch;
```

Comment: @Paebbels fixed. thnx for your remarks. When did "stack" became a copypaste project? people might want to read and think themselves))))

Comment: @Paebbels anyway it's not a good reason to downvote newbies that try to answer)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake and confused you with my OR. The verilog code is an adder... As an appology, I fixed the code.

Comment: @Paebbels TY. now i got a question, why making it (unsigned) instead of leaving it as it is?

Comment: There are 2 kinds of addition: signed and unsigned. I'm using the IEEE.numeric_std package, which should be prefered over std_logic_arith and so on. This packages requires explizit type conversion to choose signed or unsigned. Using std_logic_arith would implizitely choose unsigned arithmetic for all std_logic_vectors. I'm not sure what the default mode for Verilog is.